# Libgit2sharp Xamarin Android integration

Tags: android, xamarin, libgit2sharp

In order to make some proof of concept prototypes, I'm planning to add git functionality to my Xamarin Android app.

For doing so, I was taking a look at the libgit2sharp library, especially the latest prereleases that seem to be released with .netstandard 2.0.

The NuGet package installation works perfectly, but obviously, it fails when I try to make any call to the library because the missing library files that are not built in the libgit2sharp.nativebinaries project.

Is there any way I can build on my own these libraries?
If not, can you think about any other alternative?

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2#android

Comment: Have you tried building the native libraries?  There are instructions at https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp.nativebinaries.  Did you have problems?  Where there error messages?